# How to convert JArray to KeyValuePair structure in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JArray with objects have two property. For example:

```
[
     {"Prop1":"key1", "Prop2":"value1"}, 
     {"Prop1":"key2", "Prop2":"value2"}, 
     {"Prop1":"key3", "Prop2":"value3"}
]
```

And I need to KeyValuePair (or Dictionary doesn't matter) structure in C# such as

```
key1-value1
key2-value2
key3-value3
```

Names of Prop1 and Prop2 also can change which means that JArray can have different prop names but number of properties in the object always will be 2. So that I need general method which deserialize the JArray to `List<KeyValuePair>` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a variable `array` of type `JArray`, you can do the following using [extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) methods from the [`System.Linq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace:

```
var pairs = array
    // Cast array items from JToken to JObject.  
    // You could filter instead using `OfType<JObject>() if nulls might be present
    .Cast<JObject>()
    // Convert the first and second property values to a KeyValuePair
    .Select(o => new KeyValuePair<string, string>((string)o.PropertyValues().ElementAtOrDefault(0), 
                                                  (string)o.PropertyValues().ElementAtOrDefault(1)))
    .ToList();

var dict = pairs.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/otpV0n)